# Why isn't my php connecting to my server?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm trying to take and get data from a database to a website using php. When I'm trying to connect I'm using this code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'test';
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($conn->connect_errno) echo "failed to connect to database";
?>
```

but upon trying to open the php file I recieve this on firefox:

```
connect_errno) echo "failed to connect to database"; ?> (on firefox)
```

and this on opera/chrome:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'test';
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($conn->connect_errno) echo "failed to connect to database";
?>
```

I have also tried loading it with internet explorer but it simply tries to save it again. I'm not understanding what I am doing wrong.

For extra detail I am trying to do this through xampp using phpmyadmin.

*Okay, I fixed it just incase anyone looks back at this essentially the issue was my misunderstanding of the instruction 'open the php'. I was opening it directly to the browser, I needed to open it via localhost.
so localhost/connect.php rather than just opening connect.php to the browser.*

Comment: Your server is configured wrong or you're not using the proper file extensions so the file is just served as it is without running through PHP

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what I may have configured wrong>?

Comment: Your server isn't running PHP, it's just dishing this out as HTML. The browser shouldn't be a factor. If it is you've got server problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure the extension of file is ".php"

2) Make sure that you are running page from "http://localhost//" or your local host ip.

You can test your apache/xampp by visiting "localhost" or "localhost:8080" if it is running on 8080 port.

Comment: I am using .php

Comment: What do you mean by localhost//

Comment: when you install xampp. Apache server, mysql services are installed. You need to start xampp and this services. Then in browser you can access your server at "http://localhost//" address.

Comment: Ah, this starts to make sense. When I load localhost I get this error:

Comment: Your xampp is not setup correctly. Please follow installation guide properly.  Once xampp home screen appears then you can start development again.